# Hatching array of circles in AutoCAD using c#

Tags: c#, autocad

I am beginner in `AutoCad Plugins`.I have created an array of circle using following code. Now, I have to hatch those circles in array .How to do that??How to hatch all circles at once? Moreover, how can i return hatch from method and use it to hatch objects.Sorry for language.Thanks in advance.

```
[assembly: CommandClass(typeof(BeamSection.Class1))]
namespace BeamSection
{
    public class Class1
    {
        //Class1 obj = new Class1();

        [CommandMethod("BeamAtSupport")]
        public void AddLightweightPolyline()
        {
            // Get the current document and database
            Document acDoc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
            Database acCurDb = acDoc.Database;
            PromptPointResult ppr = acDoc.Editor.GetPoint("\nSelect starting point ");
            var ucs = acDoc.Editor.CurrentUserCoordinateSystem;
            Point3d StartingPt = ppr.Value.TransformBy(ucs);



            List<double> radius = new List<double>();
            radius.Add(0.5);
            radius.Add(1);
           double[]   pickPont = new double[3];
            pickPont = new double[3];
            pickPont[0] = StartingPt[0];
            pickPont[1] = StartingPt[1];
            pickPont[2] = StartingPt[2];
            double w = 12.0;
            double b = 18.0;
            double t = 1.0;
            double c = 1.0;
            int nb = 3;







            // Start a transaction
            using (Transaction acTrans = acCurDb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
            {
                // Open the Block table for read
                BlockTable acBlkTbl;
                acBlkTbl = acTrans.GetObject(acCurDb.BlockTableId,
                                                OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTable;
                //Open the Block table record Model space for write
                BlockTableRecord acBlkTblRec;
                acBlkTblRec = acTrans.GetObject(acBlkTbl[BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace],
                                               OpenMode.ForWrite) as BlockTableRecord;
                pickPont[0] = StartingPt[0];
                pickPont[1] = StartingPt[1];
                pickPont[2] = StartingPt[2];
                Application.ShowAlertDialog(pickPont[0].ToString());


              double x = calculate(w, b, c, radius, nb);
              Circle acCircle = new Circle();
              acCircle.Radius = 1.5 * 0.5;
              acCircle.Center = new Point3d(pickPont[0] - (w / 2 - 2 * c) - x - 0.1, pickPont[1] + 2 * c, 0);
              //acBlkTblRec.AppendEntity(acCircle);
              //acTrans.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(acCircle, true);

            /*  ObjectIdCollection objColls = new ObjectIdCollection();
              objColls.Add(acCircle.ObjectId);
              Hatch oHatch = new Hatch();
              oHatch.Elevation = 0.0;
              oHatch.PatternScale = 2.0;
              oHatch.SetHatchPattern(HatchPatternType.PreDefined, "Solid");
              oHatch.ColorIndex = 4;

              oHatch.Associative = true;
              oHatch.AppendLoop(HatchLoopTypes.Outermost, objColls);
              oHatch.EvaluateHatch(true);*/




              //ObjectIdCollection objColls = new ObjectIdCollection();
              //objColls.Add(acCircle.ObjectId);




                /*  Matrix3d curUCSMatrix = acDoc.Editor.CurrentUserCoordinateSystem;
                  CoordinateSystem3d curUCS = curUCSMatrix.CoordinateSystem3d;
                  Vector2d acVec2dAng = new Vector2d(curUCS.Xaxis.X, curUCS.Xaxis.Y);*/

                //dArrayAng = dArrayAng; //+ acVec2dAng.Angle;
                      int nRows = 1;
                      int nColumns = nb;
                      double dRowOffset = 1;
                      double dColumnOffset = x;
                      Application.ShowAlertDialog(x.ToString());
                      double dArrayAng = 0;
                      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                      {
                          Extents3d acExts = acCircle.Bounds.GetValueOrDefault();
                          Point2d acPt2dArrayBase = new Point2d(acExts.MinPoint.X, acExts.MaxPoint.Y);



                          if (i == 1)
                          {
                              acCircle.Center = new Point3d(pickPont[0] - (w / 2 - 2 * c) - x - 0.1, pickPont[1] + 2 * c, 0);

                          }
                          else 
                          {
                              acCircle.Center = new Point3d(pickPont[0] - (w / 2 - 2 * c) - x - 0.1, pickPont[1] + (b - 3 * t) + 1, 0);
                          }
                          DBObjectCollection acDBObjCollCols = new DBObjectCollection();
                          acDBObjCollCols.Add(acCircle);

                          int nColumnsCount = 1;
                          while (nColumns >= nColumnsCount)
                          {
                              Entity acEntClone = acCircle.Clone() as Entity;




                              acDBObjCollCols.Add(acEntClone);
                              // Caclucate the new point for the copied object (move)          
                              Point2d acPt2dTo = PolarPoints(acPt2dArrayBase, dArrayAng, dColumnOffset * nColumnsCount);
                              Vector2d acVec2d = acPt2dArrayBase.GetVectorTo(acPt2dTo);
                              Vector3d acVec3d = new Vector3d(acVec2d.X, acVec2d.Y, 0);
                              acEntClone.TransformBy(Matrix3d.Displacement(acVec3d));


                              acBlkTblRec.AppendEntity(acEntClone);
                              acTrans.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(acEntClone, true);
                              nColumnsCount = nColumnsCount + 1;

                          }

                          double dAng = Math.PI / 2;

                          DBObjectCollection acDBObjCollLvls = new DBObjectCollection();
                          foreach (DBObject acObj in acDBObjCollCols)
                          {
                              acDBObjCollLvls.Add(acObj);
                          }
                          foreach (Entity acEnt1 in acDBObjCollCols)
                          {
                              int nRowsCount = 1;
                              while (nRows > nRowsCount)
                              {
                                  Entity acEntClone = acEnt1.Clone() as Entity;
                                  acDBObjCollLvls.Add(acEntClone);

                                  // Caclucate the new point for the copied object (move)              
                                  Point2d acPt2dTo = PolarPoints(acPt2dArrayBase, dArrayAng + dAng, dRowOffset * nRowsCount);
                                  Vector2d acVec2d = acPt2dArrayBase.GetVectorTo(acPt2dTo);
                                  Vector3d acVec3d = new Vector3d(acVec2d.X, acVec2d.Y, 0);
                                  acEntClone.TransformBy(Matrix3d.Displacement(acVec3d));

                                  acBlkTblRec.AppendEntity(acEntClone);
                                  acTrans.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(acEntClone, true);
                                  nRowsCount = nRowsCount + 1;
                              }
                          }
                      }





                    //acBlkTblRec.AppendEntity(oHatch);
                  //  acTrans.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(oHatch, true);





                    acTrans.Commit();
                }
                acDoc.SendStringToExecute("._zoom _e ", true, false, false);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see this [doc](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2015/ENU/?guid=GUID-01A47A4F-9FC5-4DB6-8C3E-B72D75688965).
You could add the hatch to the first circle before creating the array with both entities.

Please, clean up your code before posting it so that it should be easier to read for those who try to help.